# How do I call a function every x minutes in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

How do I call a function every x minutes.

I assume I'd have to add a timer to the form?

Comment: Yes, it would be a good way of doing things. Here's an example of how to use Timers: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/perform-actions-at-set-intervals-with-vbnets-timer-control/6150796

Comment: If what you specifically need is calling a function every x minutes then yes, the timer is the best way to go. But perhaps some insight on what are you trying to accomplish might help us give you a better approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here is a simple example:

```
Public Class SampleCallEveryXMinute

     Private WithEvents xTimer as new System.Windows.Forms.Timer

     Public Sub New(TickValue as integer)
         xTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
         xTimer.Interval = TickValue
     End Sub

     Public Sub StartTimer
         xTimer.Start
     End Sub

     Public Sub StopTimer
         xTimer.Stop
     End Sub

     Private Sub Timer_Tick Handles xTimer.Tick
         SampleProcedure
     End Sub

     Private Sub SampleProcedure
         'SomeCodesHERE
     End Sub

End Class
```

USAGE:

```
Dim xSub as new SampleCallEveryXMinute(60000) ' 1000 ms = 1 sec so 60000 ms = 1 min
xSub.StartTimer
```

Answer (score 4):

**ALTERNATIVE 1**

Here is good guide to use the [Timer Control](http://vb.net-informations.com/gui/timer-vb.htm) in VB.net.

The advantage is that you don't have to worry about modifying UI objects from non UI thread.

**ALTERNATIVE 2**

Another alternative is to spawn another thread and do the work and sleep the remaining x minutes.

The advantage here is that if your function doesn't touch UI objects your application will remain responsive to user input while the function is being called

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could add a timer to the form, and set its interval to x*60000, where x is the number of minutes between calls.

Remember that the timer runs on the UI thread, so don't do anything intensive in the function. Also, if the UI thread is busy, the timer event will not fire until the UI thread finishes whatever event it is currently processing. If your function is going to be CPU-intensive, then consider having the timer start up a background worker

If you require a longer time period between function calls (ie, one thats too big for a timer interval) then you could have a timer function that fires every minute, and increments a counter until the desired amount of time has passed, before going on to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Private Sub Form_Load() 
            _timer.Enabled = True
    End Sub 

    Private Sub _timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "," + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
    End Sub
```