# vb.net How do I refresh the data for every 5 seconds?

Tags: vb.net

I just want that for every 5 seconds, this `Student function` refresh, in my current behavior, i need to click button so that the `Student function` refresh,

```
Private Sub Mainform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
Public Function Student()
    .....
End Function

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Student()
End Sub
```

UPDATE

Consider the Stundent Function is Connected in the database (getting the data), i dont get any error when i used button to refresh the data, i dont know how to use timer and use it to get the updated the data from the database for every 5 seconds

this is the error i get

[image]

Comment: Not sure which framework you are using, I am assuming Winforms. Use the Timer Control  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0

Comment: @MarkHall I use vb.net windows form, not c#

Comment: @MarkHall, there is no `Timer` control. Only classes that inherit `Control` are controls, which `Timer` does not. `Timer` does inherit `Component`, so it is a component, which is all that's required to be used in the designer. Controls are specialised components.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813004/how-do-i-call-a-function-every-x-minutes-in-vb-net) on this very site was the third result when I searched for *"vb.net perform action at regular intervals"*. If you want to be an effective developer then you need to be able to search the web effectively. That requires no programming experience. You should ALWAYS have searched the web thoroughly before posting a question here.

Comment: I just Updated my question , please see

Comment: If you want to do something every 5 seconds, why would you set the `Interval` to 1 second?

Comment: @jmcilhinney mybad

Comment: OK, so you've updated the code. What's the actual problem then?

Comment: In my title, I just want to update the data that in the form for every 5 seconds

Comment: When I ask "what's the problem" I don't expect you to tell me what you want to achieve. I expect you to tell me what problem you're having achieving it. You asked how to execute your (VERY badly-named) `Student` method every 5 seconds and we have told you how and you appear to have done it. WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?!

Comment: BTW, you should set properties in the designer if you know there values at design time. If you know the `Interval` should be 5000 then set that in the designer. You can also set `Enabled` to `True` and avoid calling `Start`. Note that that will start the `Timer` when the form is created, rather than when it is first displayed. That is likely to be a very short period though, so probably wouldn't matter. If you're concerned, stick with calling `Start` in the `Load` event handler.

Comment: Okay, i will update the question then

Comment: That issue has got nothing to do with the `Timer`. As I posted in my answer, you can execute any code in a `Tick` event handler that you can execute in any other event handler. You asked how to do something every 5 seconds and you were told  how. Question answered. End of story. If you now have an issue with the code inside that `Student` method then that is a completely separate question and should be posted as a separate question, with just the information relevant to that issue. Please visit the Help Center and learn how to use this site correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms is event-driven, which means that the application basically waits for an event to be raised and then executes the code in the handler for that event. Common events are the `Load` of the form, the `Click` of a `Button` and the `TextChanged` of a `TextBox`. Had you done some appropriate research on the web, you'd have found that you can use a `Timer` to raise its `Tick` event at regular intervals. You can execute any code in that `Tick` event handler that you can in any other event handler.

Just note that the event is raised on the UI thread, so any code the handler contains will be executed on the UI thread. If that code takes significant time to execute, the user will notice the UI freeze during that period. If you want to avoid that, you can use a `System.Timers.Timer` instead of a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. It will raise its `Elapsed` event on a background thread, thus avoiding freezing the UI. You would then have to marshal to the UI thread in order to update any controls based on the code you executed, but that's a different question.